# How to transform an Android device into a Web Server

Tags: php, android, mysql, server

I would like to install a server (with php and MySql Database) into an Android device and then make it accessible from the Internet with an URL. Is there a way to do it without any port forwading?

Comment: This question might be better on an Android-dedicated stack, such as https://android.stackexchange.com, but I cannot be sure of it would fit their standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install that all but your server will not be reachable without port forwarding from the internet if the device uses wifi.

Also if the internet connection is done using a sim card it will not work. This time because your provider will block incoming connections.

Only with a client on the same local lan network it will work out of the box. –